# How do I use subprocess.check_output()?

Tags: python

I want to run the following command from within a Python program:
`python py2.py -i test.txt`

I tried using `subprocess.check_output` as follows:

```
py2output = subprocess.check_output(['python py2.py', '-i', 'test.txt'])
py2output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'py2.py', '-i', 'test.txt'])
```

Comment: What exactly happened when they didn't work?

Comment: Trying to run a Python 2 file through Python 3?  No, not gonna happen.  Python 3 is intentionally not backwards-compatible with Python 2.  You'd have to run `2to3` for *starters* to get your file to work in Python 3.

Comment: @Makoto: He's trying to run the Python 2 interpreter from within a Python 3 script, which is perfectly reasonable. (And from his previous question, happen to know that he's specifically doing it as a workaround for exactly the problems you're thinking of, but that isn't relevant here.)

Comment: Show us your py2.py script, what gets printed, and what ends up in py2output (assuming it returns instead of raising).

Comment: Also, the whole thing about Python 2, and about how you expect `py2.py` to interpret the arguments, is irrelevant to the question. It confused at least one person (Makoto) who probably would otherwise have given you a good answer, and probably confused or scared off others too. In the future, you'll probably get better answers if you can provide a minimal example, with no extraneous distractions.

Comment: +1 on that last comment.  When I test Python programs using `subprocess` I tend to use the Unix built-in `yes` because it's very light weight and generates an infinite number of lines all containing the single character "y".

Comment: Tangentially, `'python'` is already a string, so calling `str()` on it is completely redundant.

Comment: Having said that, your final attempt should have worked if the `py2.py` script worked; the `check` element would cause Python to throw an explicit error telling you what's wrong if it failed.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The right answer (using Python 2.7 and later, since `check_output()` [was introduced then](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)) is:

```
py2output = subprocess.check_output(['python','py2.py','-i', 'test.txt'])
```

To demonstrate, here are my two programs:

py2.py:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

py3.py:

```
import subprocess
py2output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'py2.py', '-i', 'test.txt'])
print('py2 said:', py2output)
```

Running it:

```
$ python3 py3.py
py2 said: b"['py2.py', '-i', 'test.txt']\n"
```

Here's what's wrong with each of your versions:

```
py2output = subprocess.check_output([str('python py2.py '),'-i', 'test.txt'])
```

First, `str('python py2.py')` is exactly the same thing as `'python py2.py'`—you're taking a `str`, and calling `str` to convert it to an `str`. This makes the code harder to read, longer, and even slower, without adding any benefit.

More seriously, `python py2.py` can't be a single argument, unless you're actually trying to run a program named, say, `/usr/bin/python\ py2.py`. Which you're not; you're trying to run, say, `/usr/bin/python` with first argument `py2.py`. So, you need to make them separate elements in the list.

Your second version fixes that, but you're missing the `'` before `test.txt'`. This should give you a `SyntaxError`, probably saying `EOL while scanning string literal`.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure how you found documentation but couldn't find any examples with arguments. The very first example is:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
b'Hello World!\n'
```

That calls the `"echo"` command with an additional argument, `"Hello World!"`.

Also:

> -i is a positional argument for argparse, test.txt is what the -i is

I'm pretty sure `-i` is *not* a positional argument, but an optional argument. Otherwise, the second half of the sentence makes no sense.

Comment: now I tried with 2 arguments in argparse. I tried to put this command into subprocess: `python py2.py -i test.txt -l ong` I tried this subprocess based on your answer: `py2output=subprocess.check_output(["python","py2.py","-i","test.txt","-l","ong"])` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1925847: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? That's not a helpful comment. If you do it right, it works—as my answer demonstrates. So obviously you've done something wrong. But it's impossible to guess what. As I said in a comment on the main question: show us your scripts, and tell us what the expected and actual output is, or there's no hope of guessing what you're doing wrong.

Comment: and don't forget to catch CalledProcessError **and** OSError exceptions.

Comment: I recommend using the function shlex.split("python py2.py -i test.txt") to split a string into a list of arguments.

Comment: question: how come `subprocess.check_output(['cd', 'C:\'])` doesn't work? I get "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: @AdrianKeister Why are you asking this as a comment to a completely different question that just happens to mention `subprocess`? I'm 99% sure your question already exists, as its own question, on SO. But briefly: `subprocess` runs a program. There's no program named `cd`. There's a built-in command in the `cmd` command-line interpreter shell (aka "DOS prompt") called `cd`, which changes the current directory for that shell. You can run a new shell to execute `cd` on that shell (with `['cmd', '/c', 'cd', path]` or by using `shell=True`), but that would be pretty pointless.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Meanwhile, if you want to change the current working directory for your program (and other subprocesses you launch), just use `os.chdir`.

Answer (score 71):

**Since Python 3.5,** [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) instead of [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api):

```
>>> subprocess.run(['cat','/tmp/text.txt'], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
b'First line\nSecond line\n'
```

**Since Python 3.7,** instead of the above, you can use `capture_output=True` parameter to capture stdout and stderr:

```
>>> subprocess.run(['cat','/tmp/text.txt'], check=True, capture_output=True).stdout
b'First line\nSecond line\n'
```

Also, you may want to use `universal_newlines=True` or its equivalent since Python 3.7 `text=True` to work with text instead of binary:

```
>>> stdout = subprocess.run(['cat', '/tmp/text.txt'], check=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
>>> print(stdout)
First line
Second line
```

Comment: In this option: subprocess.run(['ls','-la'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).stdout you have the lines with a newline for python 3.6

Comment: Shouldn't this have `check=True` to be equivalent to `subprocess.check_output`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, you're right. Edited.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq All `subprocess` methods have two modes; pass a list of strings, with `shell=False` (the default); or pass in a single string for the shell to parse, with explicit `shell=True`. What exactly works also depends on whether you are on Windows or a Unix-like platform. See also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 15):

Adding on to the one mentioned by @abarnert

a better one is to catch the exception

```
import subprocess
try:
    py2output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'py2.py', '-i', 'test.txt'],stderr= subprocess.STDOUT)  
    #print('py2 said:', py2output)
    print "here"
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print "Calledprocerr"
```

this **stderr= subprocess.STDOUT** is for making sure you dont get the filenotfound error in stderr- which cant be usually caught in filenotfoundexception, else you would end up getting

```
python: can't open file 'py2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Infact a better solution to this might be to check, whether the file/scripts exist and then to run the file/script

Answer (score 1):

@ravi.zombie's answer adapted to work for **python 3** and produce output even when there is an non zero exit code error:

```
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(['git','commit','-m', commit_message], stderr= subprocess.STDOUT ).decode()
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print ('[ERROR]: Exit code != 0')
    out = e.output.decode()
print(out)
```