# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects : Python error

Tags: python

I have

Following piece of code:

```
for src_filename, src_code in src_dict.iteritems(): 
try:
set.dependencies = subprocess.check_output('unifdef -s /home/c/maindir/folder/' +src_filename, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
       print "code is bad" +set.property
       set.bad = 1
       raise
set.dependencies = list(set(set.dependencies.splitlines()))
```

I wanted to un-hardcode the path
so I wrote following piece of code:

```
filepath = os.path.join(maindirpath, "folder/")
```

maindir is argument here: /home/c/maindir

```
 path = open(filepath)
 set.dependencies = subprocess.check_output("unifdef" '-s' path +src_filename, shell=True)
```

It throws following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects
```

I am new to python. can anybody help, where I am getting wrong?

Comment: Clearly, `src_filename` is a file object, not a filename, despite its name misleadingly claiming otherwise.

Comment: Also, `shell=True` is evil, and your code has security bugs because of it (see what happens if `src_filename` is `"hello $(rm -rf .).txt"`.

Comment: It's noteworthy, by the way, that you show how you're getting `filepath` and `path`, but not `src_filename`, which is the argument you *actually use*. Please, in the future, check that your code can be copied-and-pasted to reproduce the problem that you're asking about with no prior setup needed. See also: http://sscce.org/

Comment: basically I want to keep the code same, just instead of hardcode path wants to use the 'path'.

Comment: You have invalid syntax in the third code block (`"unifdef" '-s' path +src_filename`). Please post the real code, and the traceback given with the error.

Comment: `path` is a file. To get the filename use `path.name`,

Comment: Ahh! This update clarifies things a bit. It's still not a SSCCE, since other people can't copy/paste/run it (unless they have `src_dict` defined), but it makes it clear that a big misleading issue is bad choice of variable names: `src_filename` isn't a filename, it's a file, so you should probably name it `src_file`.

Comment: yes that's true. its a file. my issue is only that I don't want to enter that hardcoded path each time. I am taking maindir from user, it should join with folder and make use of it. But since i am new to python, my every try is failing.

Comment: Are you trying to open a directory with `path = open(filepath)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for src_file, src_code in src_dict.iteritems():

  # assuming, here, that you want to honor the handle's path if already given
  filename = src_file.name
  if not '/' in filename:
    filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)

  try:
    set.dependencies = subprocess.check_output(['unifdef', '-s', filename])
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    pass # etc.
```

By the way, `set` is a bad variable name, since `set` is also a Python data type; you're making the data type unusable in your code by shadowing it with a like-named variable. Don't do that!

Comment: You have a file object. The file that the object is backed by already includes a path in its name, unless you're trying to refer to a like-named file in a different directory.

Comment: In the "refer to a like-named file in a different directory" case, use the `basename()` approach suggested by sancho.s -- but, ideally, couple it with the subprocess usage pattern given here, where you **don't** use `shell=True`.

Comment: *shrug*. I can't reproduce your bug, so that report does nobody any good. If your code were a proper SSCCE (particularly, **self-contained**), we could test our implementations and know what they did or didn't do, but your question here isn't usefully described enough to let anyone test their answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate `'unifdef -s /home/c/maindir/folder/'`
with `src_filename`
The first is a string, so the second is likely a file object.

As per your edited version, you probably need

```
bytestr = subprocess.check_output( [ 'unifdef', '-s', filepath + os.path.basename(src_filename.name) ] )
```

instead of

```
set.dependencies = subprocess.check_output("unifdef" '-s' path +src_filename, shell=True)
```

(remember that `subprocess.check_output` [returns a byte string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)).
Then assign `bytestr` to whatever you need.

You might even want

```
try :
    bytestr = subprocess.check_output( [ 'unifdef', '-s', filepath + os.path.basename(src_filename.name) ], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError :
    ...
```

This may work, although it is quite rudimentary, and you probably have much better options workable with the rest of your code (which we do not know).

See [How do you use subprocess.check_output() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078117/how-do-you-use-subprocess-check-output-in-python)

Comment: That is true. How can I rearrange code so that instead of hardcode path. it will take path and concatenate it with src_filename

Comment: @geek_xed, how can we tell you how to rearrange code you aren't giving us in the first place? Your question needs to include code that *works to reproduce the problem*, per the rules at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code is very big. I can't copy paste. I am getting error at that statement only. I am not sure how to make use of path.

Comment: @geek_xed, the MCVE and SSCCE links I've given you show you how to break down a big piece of code to a minimal reproducer. It's work, but then, you're asking us to do work for you; it's only fair that you do some work too. :)

Comment: @sancho.s, better, but do we really want to be encouraging someone to pass `src_filename.name` to a shell, when we don't know that that name will parse back to itself? Think about what happens if the name contains spaces. It'd be less buggy to use `pipes.quote` or its Python 3 `shlex.quote` replacement, but even better to modify the code to not use `shell=True`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - You are absolutely right. The code posted is only intended to get the OP going, not to be fail safe.

Comment: @sancho.s, yes, but if we "get someone going" by showing them a practice that has subtle (hard-to-catch) bugs, when will they ever learn the right way?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - They might, or they might not. This is pointing out the specific error the OP made. All aspects are worth commenting on (the specific source of the `TypeError`, use of `subprocess.check_output`)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand, here is what I would try:

```
import os

D = os.getcwd()           # returns a string
newD = (D + '/folder/')   # concatenates the two strings together
```

I use this all the time, if os.getcwd() (get current working directory) isn't exactly what you are looking for, there are similar options under the os module that will also return a string.  As I am sure you know, typing help(os) in IDLE should show you all the options.