# subprocess.check_output does not detect path

Tags: python

This is link to my older post in this connection
[cannot concatenate 'str' and 'file' objects : Python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329759/cannot-concatenate-str-and-file-objects-python-error)

My code is now as below:

```
for src_filename, src_code in src_dict.iteritems():
try:
   if src_filename == "weigh_of_the_fruit.c":
      src_filepath = os.path.join(maindir, "folder/")
      filename = src_filename
      if not '/' in filename:
         filename = os.path.join(src_filepath, filename)
      a = open(filename, "r")
   src_dict[src_filename] = subprocess.check_output("unifdef" +'-D'+definedFlags + '-U' +undefinedFlags+ filename, shell = True)

except:
      subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
      # code
```

so I get an error on

```
src_dict[src_filename] = subprocess.check_output("unifdef" +'-D'+definedFlags + '-U' +undefinedFlags+ filename, shell = True)
```

I think this line doesn't detect the path - filename 
maindir is a path of repo and argument taken from command line.

P.S: I solved this problem. It was syntax error. I had to code space

Comment: I followed a suggestion given by Charley in linked post. so basically filename is a path.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: it doesn't try src_dict statement and jumps to except and calls subprocess.CalledProcessError. it should not do so, if src_filename == 'weight_of_the_fruit.c". so I think it is not detecting filename.

Comment: moreover if I remove filename and put "/c/home/maindir/folder/"+src_filename, the code works fine.

Comment: This code won't run as written due to the indentation problems (which makes it hard to figure out if your problem is maybe just basic syntax).  Can you ensure that you have posted a runnable sample?

Comment: this is part of very big code. but i have pasted the code as it is.