# How to start, stop and get output from another python program

Tags: python

I would like to be able to start, stop and get the console output of another python program. I don't want to run it within the current program, I want them to run as two separate instances.

Both of the files are in the same directory.

I have seen guides on how to get the console output of another python program, as well as how to start and stop it, but I haven't been able to find a guide on both.

I should also note that the file I want the output from is a .pyw file.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Not a duplicate, it is not that simple...

**EDIT2:**

Here is my attempt

`main.py`

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'sub.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
# continue with your code then terminate the child
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line)
p.wait()
```

`sub.py`

```
import time

for i in range(100):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

It sort of works, but it prints it like

> b'0\r\n' b'1\r\n' b'2\r\n' b'3\r\n' b'4\r\n'

**EDIT3:**

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'sub.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", ""))
p.wait()
```

Is this the best way?

However, I am still having issues. I want to run the program completely separately, and so I should be able to run other code in the `main.py` program at the same time, but that is not working.

```
import subprocess
import time


def get_output():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'sub.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    with p.stdout:
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            print(line.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", ""))
    p.wait()


def print_stuff():
    for i in range(100):
        print("." + str(i))
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_output()
    print_stuff()
```

```
import time


def main():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**EDIT4:**
Here is my attempt at running them both at the same time

```
import subprocess
import asyncio


async def get_output():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'sub.py', 'watch', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    with p.stdout:
        for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
            print(line.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", ""))
    p.wait()


async def print_stuff():
    for i in range(100):
        print("." + str(i))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
        print_stuff(),
        get_output()
    ))
    loop.close()
```

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    for i in range(100):
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The expected output is

> .0 0 .1 1 .2 2 ...

But the output is

> .0 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...

**EDIT5:**
I believe the issue is that `subprocess.Popen` holds the program, so I think I need to use `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec`m but I can't figure out exactly how to get that to work.

Comment: @Xosrov no it is not

Comment: "I have seen guides on how to get the console output of another python program, as well as how to start and stop it, but I haven't been able to find a guide on both." -- Really? You know how to do A, and you know how to do B, but you can't figure out to do A then B?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes that is correct

Comment: I mean, can you explain more clearly how far you have gotten, and exactly where you are stuck?

Comment: @Blorgbeard  Please see the edit

Comment: @Prune Please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it when I asked a similar question.  I also needed the output as soon as it was printed, *not* waiting for a buffer to fill.

**CHILD PROCESS**

```
from time import sleep

# Dummy child process for popen demonstration
# Print "sleeping" at 1-sec intervals, then a "QUIT" message.

for _ in range(5):
    print(_, "sleeping")
    sleep(1)

print("Child process finishes")
```

**PARENT PROCESS**

```
import subprocess
import time

# Turn off output buffering in Python;
#   we need each output as soon as it's printed.
environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"

# Locate the child's source file -- YOU can use a local path.
branch_root = environ["PYTHONPATH"]
cmd = ["/usr/bin/python3", branch_root + "popen_child.py"]

# Start the child process, opening a pipe from its stdout
# Include stderr under stdout.
test_proc = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd,
    universal_newlines=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)

print(time.time(), "START")

# Catch and print the output as it's generated.
for out_data in iter(test_proc.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(time.time(), out_data, end="")

print("TEST completed")
```

Turning the "listening" on and off is a matter of attention in the parent process.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. However, I realised that it does not by default allow me to run other code at the same time, and that is the only reason I'm running it from another file - I want them to essentially run independently. I edited my post again to add some clarification.

Comment: I just posted my own answer, do you think that is unbuffered as well? Or do I need to make some changes?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the initial comment.
I know a method but I'm not sure it works on all operating systems. It involves the `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
import os
#another python file with possible inputs
command = "python3 test2.py"
#get current file dir as thats where test2.py is located
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
#gets outputs printed on the terminal
process = subprocess.check_output(command.split(), cwd=fileDir)
print(process)
```

This method also ensures the second scripts is done before continuing the main code.
Edit: Output is in byte form, decode with something like `process.decode('utf-8')`
More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078117/how-do-you-use-subprocess-check-output-in-python)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, but I need it to give a constant live update of the output of the other program, but I would also like to run other code at the same time.