# get pid of process created with subprocess.check_call()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am currently trying to get the process id of a process started with subprocess.check_call.

i.e.

```py
from subprocess import check_output

# I want to retrieve the PID of this process:
try:
    p = check_output(['some broken program']) 
except:
    if CalledProcessError: # but Popen does not throw me a CalledProcessError even if program crashes
        print("triage some stuff")
        print(p.pid) # this doesn't work unless its Popen
```

I have tried using Popen which works perfectly, however, it doesn't seem to be able to catch when a program is terminated i.e. `CalledProcessError`.

Can anyone advise, whether there is a way to get around either problem? Thanks!

Comment: Post your code so it's more clear

Comment: For all of the `subprocess` functions other than `Popen()`, you don't get control back until the called process has exited, so there *is* no pid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to import CalledProcessError too. Code (with check_output): `from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError`
2. To detect a specific exception you have to use the following syntax:

   ```
    try:
        statement
    except ExceptionName:
        another_statement
   ```

   In your situation:

   ```
    try:
        p = check_output(['some broken program']) 
    except CalledProcessError:
        print("triage some stuff")
   ```
3. You cannot reference p inside the `except` block as p may be undefined.
4. Moreover, as stated [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758810/8551315), `subprocess.run()` is recommended over `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: so... the question still stands. are there any methods that I can catch the `CalledProcessError` exception when using Popen?